# Exclude simple mails from MailChimp

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mailchimp

I have a MailChimp account which is linked to my Wordpress website and it's doing its job very well but I want to send a simple email with `wp_mail()` and i want it to be different from MailChimp template ( including some variables from database ). I understand that MailChimp is for newsletters but i want to find a way to send simple emails from Wordpress and send newsletters from MailChimp.

Right now when I send emails with `wp_mail()` I get 2 emails: 1 from Wordpress and 1 from MailChimp and I want to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the following plugin

[Disable Emails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emails/)

The plugin itself disables the wp_mail() default function for wordpress.

Comment: Ok then how am i supposed to send emails from php code then ?